# How to solve this function?

Tags: functions

I've been doing some refresher problems and stuck on this one. How to solve the following:
If $f(x) = 3^{x-1}$ and $f(a)= \frac 19$, then a = ?

Options:
a) –2
 b) –1
 c) 1
 d) 2
 e) 3

Thanks!

Comment: $$3^{a1}=\frac{1}{9}?$$

Comment: @DenisIvanov, should it be $x+1$ or $x-1$ etc. instead of $x1$?

Comment: As I see it, the problem is probably flawed... There is something wrong with the definition. Here is the link (problem 17) http://www.lavc.cc.ca.us/math/samples/precalc/index.html

Comment: Nevermind, there was a glitch on the page for some reason and it gave me some weird definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Observe that $$f(a)=\frac19=3^{-2}$$